# If $A\subset B\subset G$ and $A\le G$, do we have $A\le B$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group, $A \subset B \subset G$. If $A \leq G$, then does $A \leq B$ hold? $( H \leq G$ means that $H$ is a subgroup of $G.)$

I think this holds.

$(1)$ $A \subset B$.

$(2)$ $e \in A$ since $A \leq G$.

$(3)$ $a \in A \Rightarrow a^{-1} \in A$ since $A \leq G$.

$(4)$ $a,b \in A \Rightarrow ab \in A$ since $A \leq G$.

From $(1)$ to $(4)$, $A \leq B.$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's false as $B$ might not be a subgroup, so it does not make sense to say that $A$ is a subgroup of $B$. Example: $G = \mathbb Z_4$, $A = \{ 0,2\}$, $B \supset A$ and has three elements. $B$ cannot be a subgroup (say, by Lagrange theorem).

If $B$ happens to be a subgroup of $G$, then your assertion and proof are both correct.